# Code to submit the email form without refreshing the page and without validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a contact form using requires attribute. Now i want to submit this email form without refreshing the page. When i googled it, I got with the validation code, i don't need validation because i used required attribute in my html. I just want that function which i can add so that the page wont be refreshed after submitting and email should go..

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 Contact Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css">
    </head>     
    <body>
        <div id="contact">
            <form class="contact_form" action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                         <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                         <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required /> <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="message">Message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="6" required></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];
    $mail_to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
    $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) {
        ?>

        </script>
    <?php
     } else { ?>

    <?php
     } 
?>
```

I dont know what to add inside if and else cases to achieve my objective? Please help me out..

Comment: I think if you don't want the page to be refreshed. You should probably use `ajax` or `post` method defined in the `Jquery` library like @mnm suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `jQuery`'s `ajax` function to send a form without refreshing the page, here's the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think the OP wants to modify the code they **already** have, instead of rewriting most of it...

Answer (score 0):

Just use this as `contact.php`

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
$mail_to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
?>
```